# Stream find method - getting an out of memory

Tags: scala

Can somebody help me with what I may be missing here:

```
def isDivisibleByRange(n: Int, r: Range) = {
    r.forall(n % _ == 0)
}  

def from(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n #:: from(n + 1)
```

Now, the following gives me an OOM:

```
val o = from(1).find(isDivisibleByRange(_, Range(2, 21)))
```

Comment: My first guess would be that Scala is not smart enough to know that the earlier entries in the stream can no longer be accessed and can be thrown away. Perhaps the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216774/) will be useful.

Comment: it is not smart enough. It is smart. change it r.forall(n % _ == 0) to r.forall(_ % n == 0)

Comment: @dfan if I get you correctly, they shouldn't be thrown away, that is the distinction between Stream and Iterator.

Comment: @dfan you are wrong about the forall condition. change r.forall(n % _ == 0) to r.forall(_ % n == 0).

Comment: @Cloud tech I didn't mention a forall condition, but his forall condition is fine. He wants to know what numbers are divisible by all factors from 2 to 20, so he tries dividing by every number in the range. Your suggestion would look for numbers that are a factor of every number from 2 to 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's step through your code a bit:

```
from(1) // 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ...
isDivisibleByRange(1, Range(2, 21)
Range(2, 21).forall(1 % _ == 0) // false
isDivisibleByRange(2, Range(2, 21)
Range(2, 21).forall(2 % _ == 0) // false
isDivisibleByRange(3, Range(2, 21)
Range(2, 21).forall(3 % _ == 0) // false
... OOME
```

The first number to satisfy `(2 to 21) mod == 0` is `232792560`. So you get an OOME before you reach `232792560`.

Since stream is just a lazy list, you're basically creating a list of all possible positive integers, which takes all your memory. Maybe increase your heap space? Remember that there's some extra allocation around the stream container, not just 4 bytes for the int, so maybe `-Xmx4G`.

**UPDATE**

Using an iterator approach, you can do this in decent time with minimal memory (`find` on `Range` is implemented with an `Iterator`):

```
Range(1, Int.MaxValue).find(r => Range(2, 21).forall(r1 => r % r1 == 0))
//Some(232792560)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, the problem is with `Stream.find`, or rather the `find` in `LinearSeqOptimized` where the method is inherited from:

```
override /*IterableLike*/
def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    if (p(these.head)) return Some(these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }
  None
}
```

This method has been written to run with a while loop, instead of using recursion. For non-lazy sequences this won't use any extra memory and will run faster than a recursive solution. Unfortunately, `Stream` is lazy, and when this method is used with large (esp. infinite) sequences it leads to runaway memory consumption. This happens because the method always keeps its `this` pointer on the stack, and so the garbage collector never collects the beginning, or any of the rest of, the `Stream`.

The problem can be fixed by writing a `find` that works recursively:

```
import annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def betterFind[A](s: Stream[A], p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
  if (s.isEmpty)
    None
  else if (p(s.head))
    Some(s.head)
  else
    betterFind(s.tail, p)
}
```

In practice, it may be simpler to use `Stream.iterator.find` rather than writing your own method. `Stream.iterator` returns an `Iterator` over the elements of the `Stream`, and will be safe to use even with infinite streams.

Comment: why don't you contribute such specialization?

Comment: I'm actually thinking about doing that. I'll probably file a bug first though, Stream really shouldn't be inheriting from `LinearSeqOptimized`.